# Swapping multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set similar to this:

```
ID. Names 
1.  Myra
2.  John
3.  Dan
4.  James
5.  Sam
```

I need a query to swap the Names of adjacent Ids.

Expected output

```
ID. Names 
1.  John
2.  Myra
3.  James
4.  Dan
5.  Sam
```

I have tried using Case but that doesn't cover the future data entries.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything

Answer (score 0):

Very strange.  You can use window functions:

```
select id, name,
       (case when id % 2 = 1 then lead(name) over (order by id)
             else lag(name) over (order by id)
        end) as swapped_name
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming consecutive ids...

```
SELECT name FROM my_table x ORDER BY ROUND(x.id/2), x.id DESC;
```